# NGINX Keeps Crashing, Seems to be because of too many open files

Tags: nginx, debian, files

As stated in the title, my Nginx server seems to be crashing constantly although the reason is unknown.

I do have some hints from my error log which may lead to the issue.

I have tried to increase the open file limit, which has some affect, but to no serious avail.

```
2015/09/29 17:18:01 [crit] 20560#0: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)
2015/09/29 17:18:01 [crit] 20560#0: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)
```

I have tried to increase the limit, but I see this in my error log also

```
2015/09/29 17:18:02 [alert] 20632#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 300000000) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2015/09/29 17:18:02 [alert] 20633#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 300000000) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2015/09/29 17:18:02 [alert] 20560#0: recvmsg() truncated data
```

How do I give permission to increase the file limit?

Also, is this even the reason my server is crashing?

Thank you!

Just checked some more data, I have edited my files, but for some reason when checking the hard limit it says 4096?

```
root@nalsec:~# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 0
fs.file-max = 2500000000000000000
root@nalsec:~# ulimit -Hn
4096
```

Which contrasts with my fs.file-max

I tried this, and it says I don't have permission (I am root)

```
root@nalsec:~# ulimit -Hn 1000000000
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

I have edited this file already to no avail nano /etc/security/limits.conf

```
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

# End of file
nginx       soft    nofile  10240000000000000000000
nginx       hard    nofile  10240000000000000000000
*         hard    nofile      10240000000000000000000000
*         soft    nofile      10240000000000000000000000
root      hard    nofile      10240000000000000000000000
root      soft    nofile      10240000000000000000000000
www-data soft nofile 1024000000000000000
www-data hard nofile 1024000000000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

`fs.file-max` is a system-wide limit on the *total* number of file descriptors that can be open on the system.  It has no impact on the per-process limit.

To increase the file descriptor limit for individual processes, it's easiest to do it via `limits.conf`:

```
# cat /etc/security/limits.d/nofile.conf
* soft nofile 10000
* hard nofile 1000000
```

That'll give all processes 10,000 file descriptors by default, with the ability to request an upgrade to 1,000,000 (via `setrlimit`) if they want.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response I am currently getting this

Comment: cat /etc/security/limits.d/nofile.conf
cat: /etc/security/limits.d/nofile.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: I was showing you what to put into that file -- you'll need to create it and put the contents I showed.

Comment: I have already edited a file with a different name with similar contents nano /etc/security/limits.conf

Should I still create the new file?

Comment: Ok I have added the new file anyway with the following contents 

# cat /etc/security/limits.d/nofile.conf
* soft nofile 100000000000000000
* hard nofile 100000000000000000000000

Comment: It's still puking errors 2015/09/29 18:06:37 [alert] 24016#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 300000000) failed (1: Operation not permitted)

Comment: You'll need to logout and back in again to get the larger limits applied to your session.  If the machine isn't being used for anything, a reboot is the most effective way to ensure the limits are adjusted everywhere.